# customizing angular ng-grid checkbox css

Tags: css, angularjs, checkbox

Has anyone done this? I've tried googling and it seems no one has done such a thing

the checkbox class in ng-grid is this

```
.ngSelectionCheckBox
```

Following csscheckbox's instructions i'm still not able to produce anything?!

also, when the checkbox gets checked i'm not sure where the label is, as its it just shows up as checked on console.

```
  input[type=checkbox].ngSelectionCheckBox {
                        display:none;
                    }

                    input[type=checkbox].ngSelectionCheckBox + label.css-label {
                        padding-left:41px;
                        height:36px; 
                        display:inline-block;
                        line-height:36px;
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        background-position: 0 0;
                        font-size:36px;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                        cursor:pointer;

                    }

                    input[type=checkbox].ngSelectionCheckBox:checked + label.css-label {
                        background-position: 0 -36px;
                    }
                    label.css-label {
            background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_33530f28ddc2749646023b2ef2a90882.png);
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
```

this is what i've attempted. The display none works but overriding it doesn't seem to work....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do that input[type="checkbox"] + .ngSelectionCheckBox{ display: none; }.